# Creating a custom iOS Jailbreak keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, jailbreak, theos

I have developed a custom input method and now would like to develop a tweak that would register it as a keyboard in iOS.

There are many different keyboards in Cydia (mainly from Chinese developers) such as TouchPal and Baidu Input that appear in settings as a keyboard, so it is definitely possible.

I have tried looking into the following options (barely 4 days in IDA, Xcode with theos and console):

- Text Input bundles located in /System/Library/TextInput — seems to have nothing to deal with the keyboards themselves? Some superclass headers are missing (i.e. TIZephyr... classes) so I couldn't quite figure it out. However a native integration would be awesome.
- TextInput private framework — also seems to be just for dictionary and so on
- UIKit's UIKB.. and UIKeyboard.. classes — UIKeyboardImpl seems to be something related with the keyboard functioning and UIKeyboardLayout is the thing you build upon.

I tried hooking UIKeyboardDictationLayout to just give a plain instance of a UIKeyboardLayout upon initialization — and when I tapped the mic button on the keyboard, the keyboard went blank! That kind of implementation would be nice too (even though killing dictation functionality is undesired). However, I can't find where do I send typing events as well.

So the points are:

- What is responsible for registering a class as an input method?
- What is responsible for receiving typing events?

I am asking this in hope that there are developers who had to do something similar already, because I couldn't find any articles nor anything that would give me a hint in the header files and bundles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found an interesting repo here: http://networkpx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hk.kennytm.iKeyEx3/src/ — will keep you updated on the progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it right this february even though didn't have the time to respond and it's not quite necessary now that iOS 8 has come.
Still, this is how you load your own keyboard:

```
%hook UIKeyboardInputMode

+ (id)keyboardInputModeWithIdentifier:(id)arg1 {
    id o = %orig;
    return o;
}
- (id)primaryLanguage {
    if([TegakiLayout isTegaki:[self identifier]]) return @"Tegaki";
    return %orig;
}
%end

%hook UIKeyboardImpl
/* This is where the magic is! */
+ (Class)layoutClassForInputMode:(NSString*)arg1 keyboardType:(int)arg2 {
    Class sass = %orig;
    if ([TegakiLayout isTegaki: arg1]) {
        return [TegakiLayout class];
    }
    return sass;
}
%end



extern "C" NSArray*UIKeyboardGetSupportedInputModes();
extern "C" NSArray*UIKeyboardGetActiveInputModes();
static NSArray* (*orig_modes)();
NSArray* rep_modes() {
    NSArray* res = [orig_modes() arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[@"TEGAKI", @"TEGAKI_Graffiti"]];
    return res;
}

static NSArray* (*orig_active_modes)();
NSArray* rep_active_modes() {
    NSArray* res = orig_active_modes();
    return res;
}



%ctor {
    %init;
    MSHookFunction(UIKeyboardGetSupportedInputModes, rep_modes, &orig_modes);
    MSHookFunction(UIKeyboardGetActiveInputModes, rep_active_modes, &orig_active_modes);
}
```

where TegakiLayout is a subclass of UIKeyboardLayout.

You then implement `- (BOOL)isAlphabeticPlane` for returning whether it's a traditional keyboard thing and do the custom view creation in `showKeyboardWithInputTraits:screenTraits:splitTraits:`.

To type in you then use `[[UIKeyboardImpl activeInstance]insertText:@"\n"];`.

To create a 'globe' button you use this:

```
Class sw = NSClassFromString(@"UIInputSwitcherView");
[[sw sharedInstance]selectNextInputMode];
```

Don't forget to implement `-keyboardName` and `-keyplaneName` as well!
I'll post the whole project one day probably, but for now it's too large to describe here. This should be enough to get you up and running, though.